# Calculate some function involves complex arguments by the results of real arguments

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, beta-function

Can we directly calculate some function involves complex arguments by the result of real arguments?

For example, the beta function
$$\rm{Beta}(n+1,2) = \Gamma(n+1)/\Gamma(n+3) = 1/((n+1)(n+2))$$
$$|\rm{Beta}(jn+1,2)| = |\Gamma(jn+1)/\Gamma(jn+3)| = 1/\sqrt{(n^2+1)(n^2+4)}$$
and by Wolfram Mathematica, it seems like
$\Gamma(jn+1)/\Gamma(jn+3) = 1/((jn+1)(jn+2))$.

Can we confirm $\rm{Beta}(jn+1,2) = 1/((jn+1)(jn+2))$? Can we apply the same rule to other functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @inavda Hi! I have edited the question. I hope it looks clear now...